# Multiple regression forecasting. What is the best way to obtain the forecast figures with only the summary output from regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, forecasting

[image]

Hi all,

Im not sure how I am meant to workout the forecast with just this information. I have been able to find all the missing information (the cells that are filled white) through rather simple formulas, however failed to find the forecast (cells filled yellow). Do I need more information to workout the forecast?

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't put anything in all caps. This is not the tone you are supposed to ask a question.